# Failed to load module script .. MIME type of "text/html" - Javascript, Node.js and Parcel

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to retrieve stock data using an api (yahoo-finance2 in NPM) and I've had to use parcel to get the data on the browser. Meanwhile, I wasn't being able to get this data because of CORS (yahoo was essentially blocking the requests) so now I want to create a Node.js server so I can make this data requests show up on the browser, however, I'm getting this error on the browser:

`main.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

main.js

```js
import yahooFinance from "yahoo-finance2";

async function api(symbol, start, end, val) {
  const query = String(symbol);
  const queryOptions = {
    period1: new Date(start),
    period2: new Date(end),
    interval: String(val),
  };
  let result = await yahooFinance.historical(query, queryOptions);
  let resultWithSymbol = result.map((item) => ({ ...item, symbol: query })); //... is called the spread operator - it concatonates things

  console.log(resultWithSymbol);
  return resultWithSymbol;
}
//api(symbolNew, periodStart, periodEnd, intervalNew);
api("TSLA", "2021-08-02", "2021-08-14", "1d");
```

server.js

```js
import * as http from "http";
import * as fs from "fs";

const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
  fs.readFile("./index.html", null, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.write("Whoops! File not found!");
    } else {
      res.write(data);
    }
    res.end();
  });
});

server.listen(port, hostname, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Server running at http://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/");
  }
});
```

html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" src="src/js/main.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    This is HTML
    <div class="symbol">
        <p id="symbol"></p>
        <label for="name">Symbol (4 characters):</label>
        <input type="text" id="symbol" name="symbol" required minlength="4" maxlength="4" size="10"
            placeholder="Exemplo: TSLA">

    </div>
...
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "apiparcel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "module": "./dist/esm/src/index-node.js",
  "exports": {
    "import": "./dist/esm/src/index-node.js",
    "default": "./dist/cjs/src/index-node.js"
  },
  "types": "./dist/esm/src/index-node.d.ts",
  "browser": "./dist/esm/src/index-browser.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "yahoo-finance2": "^1.14.4", 
    "ajv": "^8.1.0",
    "ajv-formats": "^2.0.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 3 and_chr versions",
    "last 3 chrome versions",
    "last 3 opera versions",
    "last 3 ios_saf versions",
    "last 3 safari versions"
  ]
}
```

How could I fix this error?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In which line of your js files is the error?

Comment: It shows up like this "main.js:1". When I click on it, it shows me the 1st line of the HTML code

Comment: #1 Does the request arrive to the main.js ? #2 is `await yahooFinance.historical` working?